# Android Studio. Roboletric. NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.SystemProperties

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying to use [Roboletric](http://robolectric.org/) in my project. Development enviroment - Android Studio 0.5.8

**app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
        classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.+'
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test');
        }
    }
}

androidTest {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-2'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-2'

    compile project('libraries:android-maps-utils')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

When I try to execute test cases using console command `gradle clean test`, console prompts error message:

```
java.lang.VerifyError      
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.SystemProperties
        at org.gradle.util.LineBufferingOutputStream.<init>(LineBufferingOutputStream.java:44)
        at org.gradle.util.LineBufferingOutputStream.<init>(LineBufferingOutputStream.java:36)
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream$1$1.run(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:35)
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream$1$1.run(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:33)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream$1.initialValue(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:33)
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream$1.initialValue(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:30)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)  
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.getStream(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.flush(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:80)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.flush(StreamHandler.java:242)
        at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.close(ConsoleHandler.java:115)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.resetLogger(LogManager.java:860)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.reset(LogManager.java:843)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner.run(LogManager.java:240)
```

Has anybody faced up with similar error?

Comment: What is your gradle version (use `gradle -v`)?

Comment: I'm using gradle 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Do other gradle commands work? The fact that it's got a VerifyError trying to initialize a Gradle class makes me think your Gradle installation is corrupted. Try deleting the .gradle directory in your home directory and also in your project root.

Comment: If it make sense I can build application with gradle. So I think other gradle commands are working.